# Is there a couniversal solution to the predicate-theoretic version of Russell's paradox?

Tags: paradox, semantics, bertrand-russell, properties

In set theory, let us call a solution to the problem of universal-sets-or-proper-classes a *couniversal* solution when it involves proposing the following:

1. ∃*U*∀*x*((*x* ≠ *U*) ⟺ (*x* ∈ *U*))

This means that *U* is a set of all *other* things (sets, there); but so now the reason why this pertains to Russell's paradox is that we should like to speak of a *well-founded* set of all *other* well-founded sets. Or, then, a noncircular set of all *other* noncircular sets, which does not trigger the paradox (or so it seems to me).

The SEP article on self-reference mentions a [semantic paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/#SemPar) akin to the set-theoretic one,  and I had thought that either the article on Russell's paradox specifically, or the broader article on paradoxes relative to contemporary logic, went over the formulation of Russell's paradox in predicate-theoretic form, but I'm having a lot of trouble finding the exact section of the exact article that I have in mind, here. At any rate, let's use, "Is 'heterological' a heterological term?" as our equivalent. (Correct me if I'm wrong about that!) **Is there a way to formulate the counterpart of a couniversal set, in predicate-theoretic (modulo set-theoretic) terms, such that a couniversal predicate(?) deflects the other form of Russell's paradox?**

Comment: Are you aware that Russel's Paradox is not the only problem with a universal set? Another problem is that the powerset of the universal set is bigger than the universal set.

Comment: @DavidGudeman both Quine's set theory NF, and Olivier Esser's positive set theory, have universal sets. The easiest way to do that modulo the powerset axiom is to just deny the powerset axiom on the universe. There is no proof that every set has a powerset anyway, hence why it's an axiom.

Comment: I should add that, to my knowledge, in the NF (or maybe NFU, I don't recall ATM) world, the powerset of the universal set is *smaller* than the universal set, which is very weird but I think has something to do with the universal set having elements that aren't able to be collected into subsets, so the number of elements the universe has altogether is greater than the number of elements that can be collected into subsets, and then the collection of those subsets is what is somehow smaller. I'll check back on the details but I'm pretty sure that's more or less how it goes, there.

Comment: How is this a solution? A solution is a principled system of set-theoretic constructions that does not produce paradoxical sets. Manufacturing "rules" motivated only by avoiding a known paradox is not it. Also, it is not the universal set that is featured in Russell's paradox but Russell's set, universal set just allows producing Russell's set by specification.

Comment: @Conifold tell all that to set theorists who propose dependent choice axioms with specifiable cardinals as indexes, or who talk about "when GCH first fails." At any rate, naive comprehension should produce a couniversal set on account of the formula for the set being naively admissible, and it is not hard to avoid an *ad hoc* modification of naive comprehension that lets this set in without also producing a self-containing set (just take foundation strictly and let in all foundation-consistent comprehensions).

Comment: For your formulaic spec there's already a famous big *almost* universal set aka Grothendieck universe consisting of small sets in the sense of category theory avoiding Russell like semantic paradoxes along with proper classes in algebraic geometry, which is compatible with well-foundedness and itself is some member of an even larger Grothendieck universe *ad infinitum*, forming some towered multiverse metaphorically. Of course non well-founded NF or positive set theory (PST) with naive comprehension also work. It's bit pity there's not much interest in PST or its opposite as amorphous sets...

Comment: 'heterological' seems like a negative predicate thus *'heterological' is a heterological term* cannot be well formed in PST metaphorically speaking but there's a positive set of all positive sets in a naive manner...